# Does JQuery "cache" DOM elements? Or is it Chrome?

Tags: jquery, caching, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a small Chrome extension to manipulate Google's search results' DOM to add a small set of questions to ask the user why s/he chose to follow that link;
while polishing, I decided to look around the page in case there was an old poll already shown, to remove it (as in, if the user decided to follow another result after s/he clicked on one), and that's when I started noticing a weird behaviour: the first time I clicked a link I got presented the poll before being able to proceed to the chosen page; the second time (without leaving the page) the old poll got correctly removed and the new one added to the DOM, but this new element got targeted by `slideDown()` only if it was inserted *before* the old one (i.e. if I clicked a link *above* the previous one).

```
$('li.g a') // all the results' link
    .bind('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // avoid going to destination right away

        var oldpoll = $('#extension');
        if (oldpoll.length)
            oldpoll.slideUp('fast', function(){
                                    $(this).remove();
                                }); // remove (eventual) old poll
        ...

        $(this).parents('.g').append(element);
        $('#extension').slideDown();
    });
```

As you can see, I figured there was some sort of caching going on and tried to "force" avoiding it by declaring a variable to hold the old element, but that didn't work; eventually, I managed to sail around it by forcing a new DOM traversal with `$('#extension a').parent().slideDown();`, but now I'm really curious about whether it's my fault, or Chrome's, or JQuery's.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `.live()` will help you: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is probably because you are inserting multiple elements with the id 'extension'. IDs are supposed to be unique in the document, but during the time that slideUp is running, there will be two '#extension' elements.

Because of that, if you insert it above the old, and then run slideDown, it will try to execute it on the new one, but if you insert it after the old element, then your slideDown will run on the old one because $('#extension') will take the first one with that id in the page.

Comment: You're right: I thought removing the old element was enough, but apparently it wasn't _fast_ enough.. I changed my code to modify the old element's `id ` before removing it, and now the new one gets inserted and "slidden" smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above as said it, there are quite a few quirks when using .bind():

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

so I would definitely recommend using [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (also being deprecated ...) or the new [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: But I don't need to target Google's results' anchor, nor I need to bind anything to my new element. I believe Logan, below, is right in saying that it's simply my fault...